# Safari browser display flex issue

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

There was an post here at Stack yesterday where someone wanted this description list snippet:

```
<dl>
  <dt>term1</dt><dd>defn1</dd>
  <dt>term2</dt><dd>defn2</dd>
  <dt>term3</dt><dd>defn3</dd>
</dl>
```

To display in this format:

```
term1 term2 term3
defn1 defn2 defn3
```

This is the css solution that I came up with:

```
div {
  width: 50%;
}

dl {
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    -moz-flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;

    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
    display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
    display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
}

dt {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0 0 30%;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    -moz-box-flex: 0 0 30%;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- */
    -moz-flex: 0 0 30%;  

    -webkit-flex: 0 0 30%;          /* Chrome */
    -ms-flex: 0 0 30%;              /* IE 10 */
    flex: 0 0 30%;                  /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */

    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;  
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;     
    -ms-flex-order: 1;     
    -webkit-order: 1;  
    order: 1;

}

dd {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0 0 30%;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    -moz-box-flex: 0 0 30%;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- */
    -moz-flex: 0 0 30%;

    -webkit-flex: 0 0 30%;          /* Chrome */
    -ms-flex: 0 0 30%;              /* IE 10 */
    flex: 0 0 30%;                  /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */

    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;  
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;     
    -ms-flex-order: 2;     
    -webkit-order: 2;  
    order: 2;

    margin-left: 0;
}
```

My problem is, and I looked thoroughly, that this css solution does not work in Safari browser only. There are exclamation marks next to display: flex and flex-wrap in the Safari browser inspector. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Which version of safari?

Comment: It is Safari 5.1.7.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flex will be supported in safari 9.0 6.1 -webkit- .. check the reference here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp 
it is better that you use width:30%; rather than flex